# Is there a way to find the last modified date of an embedded resource in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, embedded-resource

Does anybody know a way of doing this (at runtime)?

I'm not sure I can elaborate much more in the description than is already given away in the title, but if you feel I missed something do say!

Comment: Are you trying to find the date at runtime, or at compile time?

Comment: @Charlie - amended question, but runtime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The .resx file itself should have a modified date associated with it, but you won't be able to get the modified date of individual resources within that file.