# Access File information of embedded resource file

Tags: c#, file, embedded-resource, information-retrieval

I would like to access a piece of file information from an embedded resource file (in this case, the Last Modified Date) without having to save it to a temp file on the disk first.  Is this possible?

There was already one other topic asking a similar question ([goto topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999179/is-there-a-way-to-find-the-last-modified-date-of-an-embedded-resource-in-net/)) from a couple of years ago, but there was only one answer (NO) and I was hoping that someone would know of a way to do it at this point.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original answer remains correct.  When you add a file as a resource the contents of the file are stored, not the metadata (wich is stored in the file system tables).

You could add a string resource and manually populate that data before you compile.

Comment: I thought that was likely the case.  Thanks for the answer, I will use a workaround.